# Changing a spreadsheet formula so it works with PHP

Tags: php, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

for years now I have used a math formula to determine relative activity levels for message boards. Now I would like to use that formula in a php search engine to replace the non-functioning Google Page Ranking system.

The data items used are: Members (B2), Posts (D2), Topics (C2), and the Boards creation date (E2). In the spreadsheet the base formula looks like this:

```
=SUM(((((((B2/E2)+(C2/E2)+(D2/E2)))*0.419)))+((((((B2/C2)+(B2/D2))/2)+(((C2/B2)+(D2/B2))/3)-3.4777)))/7)+0.0017
```

The hard (non-generated) numbers are numbers I calculated by hand to provide output that seems to provide results close to what would be Alexa Traffic rankings and I modify them each year. The output is always held to 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your equation can be simplified quite a lot. Now, you have this:

```
=SUM(
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    (
                        (B2/E2) + (C2/E2) + (D2/E2)
                    )
                )
                *
                0.419
            )
        )
    )
    +
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    ( (B2/C2) + (B2/D2) ) / 2
                )
                +
                (
                    ( (C2/B2) + (D2/B2) ) / 3
                )
                -
                3.4777
            )
        )
    )
    /
    7
)
+
0.0017
```

The SUM function seems useless, as you have only distinct cells, not ranges. Also, a lot of the parenthesis can be removed. Thus, the function becomes this:

```
(
    (
        B2/E2 + C2/E2 + D2/E2
    )
    *
    0.419
    +
    (
        ( B2/C2 + B2/D2 ) / 2
        +
        ( C2/B2 + D2/B2 ) / 3
        -
        3.4777
    )
    /
    7
)
+
0.0017
```

Writing that as an one liner:

```
0.0017 + ((B2/E2 + C2/E2 + D2/E2) * 0.419 + ((B2/C2 + B2/D2) / 2 + (C2/B2 + D2/B2) / 3 - 3.4777) / 7)
```

To make it PHP, substitute the cell addresses with variables:

```
0.0017 + (($members / $date + $topics / $date + $posts / $date) * 0.419 + (($members / $topics + $members / $posts) / 2 + ($topics / $members + $posts / $members) / 3 - 3.4777) / 7)
```

You probably want to make a function out of that that will return the result rounded in 4 decimal places:

```
function ranking($members, $posts, $topics, $date) {
    $ranking = 0.0017 + (($members / $date + $topics / $date + $posts / $date) * 0.419 + (($members / $topics + $members / $posts) / 2 + ($topics / $members + $posts / $members) / 3 - 3.4777) / 7);

    return round($ranking, 4);
}
```

And you could call that function like this (I have no idea what the date E2 looks like, thus 30000):

```
$ranking = ranking(50, 60, 20, 30000);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: WoW! You not only solved my problem but actually helped make my spreadsheet better at the same time. The E2 takes the boards creation date and measures how long the board has been in existence. That duration number is what is used in the rest of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Without some more detail about the actual spread sheet, it's very very difficult to come up with a working solution.  In general though, you'd probably want to write a function that looks something like this:

```
function calculate_ranking($members, $posts, $topics, $creation_date) {
    return ((((((($members/$creation_date)+($topics/$creation_date)+($posts/$creation_date)))*0.419)))+(((((($members/$topics)+($members/$posts))/2)+((($topics/$members)+($posts/$members))/3)-3.4777)))/7)+0.0017;
}
```

If you post some example rows from your spreadsheet it will be much easier to craft a solution that works.  I'm not sure I fully understand what your call to the sum function did, so I removed it from my example.